# Using Heroku's Environment Variable with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When a new item is created within the database I am also storing a link with it that can be referenced to share the item. I am storing the following variable.

```
self.shareLink = "http://localhost:3000/#{self.slug}"
```

I'm having problems using the typical Root function because it excludes the "http://"portion.

Since it it hardcoded, I feel like I am doing something wrong because localhost needs to be updated when I finally push to production.

I'm using Heroku and started trying to join self.slug with a defined environment variable, however that doesn't feel correct either, I'm wondering if someone could provide some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
self.shareLink = request.protocol + request.host_with_port + '/' + self.slug
```

Or if you don't want the port:

```
self.shareLink = request.protocol + request.host + '/' + self.slug
```

**Updated:**

Since you've now stated that you need this in your model, the above won't work as the Model doesn't have access to the request.

So you can add this to your application controller to make it available everywhere:

```
before_filter :save_request

def save_request
  Thread.current[:request] = request
end
```

And then in your model do something like this to access it:

```
def my_method
  request = Thread.current[:request]
  self.shareLink = request.protocol + request.host_with_port + '/' + self.slug
end
```

Comment: I get the following error `undefined local variable or method 'request'` is there a gem I should be requiring - also this is being defined within my model